# Tab bar not show my first view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
tabbar=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ViewController * vc=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

tabbar.title=@"Home";

HomeViewController *hvc= [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

hvc.tabBarItem.title=@"Home";
hvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];

SettingViewController* svc =[[SettingViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingViewController" bundle:nil];

svc.tabBarItem.title=@"My Hospital";
svc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"myhospital.png"];


[array addObject:hvc];
[array addObject:svc];
[array addObject:vc];

tabbar.viewControllers = array;

tabbar.view.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

[self.view addSubview:tabbar.view];
```

i have written this code tab bar added succesfully but my problem is that it will directly show second window in 1st tab i want 1st view on 1st tab how may i do this thanks in advance..

Comment: Where are you doing this code - on which view lifecycle ? It looks correct - just make sure you do this on viewDidLoad.

Comment: ya i am writing this code in viewDidload()....

Comment: Ok try calling selectedIndex after addSubView then

Comment: no it's not working still display 2nd view tabbar.selectedIndex=0; adding this after add subview.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact you are adding :vc twice ? [array addObject:vc]; Maybe this is causing problem that it's not really at index 0.

Comment: By default Tab Bar controller load first controller. Try removing the tabbar.selectedIndex=0 code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to give same `ViewController` instance to first and last tab. May be that is the problem. Once again create another instance for `ViewController` class and add that class to array.

Comment: @JitendraDeore what view you have to display HomeViewController or ViewController view

Comment: dispaly correct svc and hvc but whan i tried to display first viewController Black Screen appear..

Comment: @JitendraDeore once try to give vc.tabBarItem.title and vc.tabBarItem.image

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you have added `ViewController * vc`, vc twice.

## Your code :

```
[array addObject:vc];

[array addObject:hvc];

[array addObject:svc];
```

**`[array addObject:vc];`**  <- this is wrong.

========================

Comment: i believe you wanted ViewController * vc first.

Try putting 
    [array addObject:vc]; 

as the first object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

HomeViewController *hvc = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

hvc.tabBarItem.title = @"Home";
hvc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];

SettingViewController* svc = [[SettingViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingViewController" bundle:nil];

ViewController *vc2 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

svc.tabBarItem.title = @"My Hospital";
svc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myhospital.png"];


tabbar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: vc, hvc, svc, vc2, nil];

tabbar.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

tabbar.selectedIndex = 0;

[self.view addSubview:tabbar.view];
```